# Calculate the importIVA is bad

Tags: c#

In my DataGrid I load data from the different TextBox. The amount is perfectly calculated, the problem comes with the amount with IVA. By placing it in the label below, it is correct, but then clicking on the button again, the IVA calculates it badly. I have placed BreakPoints, and the figures he catches me are correct, but multiplication is bad for me and I don't understand what happens, since in the normal Amount he does it correctly. Imagine that the IVA is 12100, when you click the first time you place it, it gives me 24200, but when you click again, it gives me about 98,000, when it would have to be half, about 48,000, and I don't understand why I do the wrong thing multiplication. I enclose the complete fragment of the code place.

```
private void btnColocar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Utilidades.ValidarFormulario(this, errorProvider1) == false)
        {
            bool existe = false;
            int num_fila = 0;

            if (cont_fila == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtCodigoPro.Text, txtDescripcion.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtCantidad.Text, txtIVA.Text);
                double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[3].Value);
                double importeIVA = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[4].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[3].Value);
                dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;
                dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[5].Value = importeIVA;

                cont_fila++;

            }

            else
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow Fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (Fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtCodigoPro.Text)
                    {
                        existe = true;
                        num_fila = Fila.Index;
                    }
                }

                if (existe == true)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(txtCantidad.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value)).ToString();
                    double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);

                    dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;

                    double importeIVA = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[5].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);
                   // double importeIVA = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[6].Value);
                    // 3
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[5].Value = importeIVA;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtCodigoPro.Text, txtDescripcion.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtCantidad.Text, txtIVA.Text);
                    double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[3].Value);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;

                    double importeIVA = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[4].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[3].Value);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[cont_fila].Cells[5].Value = importeIVA;

                cont_fila++;
                }
            }

            total = 0;
            totalIVA = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                total += Convert.ToDouble(Fila.Cells[4].Value); 
                totalIVA += Convert.ToDouble(Fila.Cells[5].Value);
            }


           lblTotal.Text = total.ToString() +  " €";
           lblIVA.Text = totalIVA.ToString() + " €";


        }

    }
```

The code crash here!!

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (Fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtCodigoPro.Text)
                    {
                        existe = true;
                        num_fila = Fila.Index;
                    }
                }

                if (existe == true)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(txtCantidad.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value)).ToString();
                    double importe = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);

                    dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[4].Value = importe;
```

///AQUÍ ES DONDE LA MULTIPLICACIÓN ME HACE COSAS RARAS

```
double importeIVA = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[5].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);

                        dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[5].Value = importeIVA;
```

Thanxx!!

Answer (score 0):

If the record doesn't exist, you calculate your IVA by multiplying the amount `Cells[3]` by `importe` (`Cells[4]`).
But if it exists, in the line

```
double importeIVA = 
    Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[5].Value) *
    Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);
```

You are multiplying the amount (`Cells[3]`) by the previously calculated IVA (`Cells[5]`) instead of the value of `importe`.

So i think it should be

```
double importeIVA = 
    Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[4].Value) *
    Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[num_fila].Cells[3].Value);
```